# UIViewController - set color of Navigation bar text on Activities popup

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uiactivityviewcontroller

Am creating a `UIActivityViewController` that is needed in both iPhone and iPad, supporting both iOS 8 and 9.

The app navigation bars are dark colored with the text appearing white-ish.

The UIActivityViewController has been subclassed and I am adding a tintColor here:

```
myActivityViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
[self.viewcontrollertoPopFrom.navigationController presentViewController:myActivityViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor myDarkerColor]];
}];
```

and also currently in the viewDidLoad of the UIActivityViewController subclass

This results in the bar appearing the way I want in the chosen activity such as email. So far so good.

The only issue I have is with the "Activities" popup that appears when the user selects the "more" button on the list of actions the user can select.

[image]

I have tried manipulating the UINavigationBar for both the system and the view in every combination I can think of to no avail. I end up with this:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO]`

This property is set to YES by default, and according to Apple's documentation:

> If you set this property to NO on a navigation bar with a translucent
>   custom background image, the navigation bar provides an opaque
>   background for the image using black if the navigation bar has
>   UIBarStyleBlack style, white if the navigation bar has
>   UIBarStyleDefault, **or the navigation bar’s barTintColor if a custom
>   value is defined**.

So setting the translucent property to `NO` and setting the `barTintColor` to your custom value should do the trick.

**UPDATE:**

It looks like because the user sorting screen ("Activities") is generated by `UIActivityViewController`, you will not be able to customize its navigation bar beyond the tint color, which appears to only affect `UIBarButtonItems`:

> UIActivityViewController is still an API only provides custom
>   functions, but not custom UI. You can’t change the way it looks. The
>   only part of visual style you can change is the icon of your custom
>   UIActivity subclass. ([Source](http://getnotebox.com/developer/uiactivityviewcontroller-ios-8/))

I am sorry to say that you will either have to stick to the system colors in `UIActivityViewController`, or create a custom control that is customizable. A quick Cocoapods search reveals that there are not any recent third-party controls that will let you do this, but I would highly encourage you to share it if you decide to!

**UPDATE 2**

Despite that the bar's tint color cannot be customized, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37623349/2292444) provides a workaround for altering the color of the bar's `navigationItem`s by setting the tint color of the application window.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I did try that. Unless I implemented it in the wrong place or something, it didn't work. Remember also, the chosen activity comes up with the right barTint.

Comment: So the same UIActivityViewController subclass is being used for "Mail" and "Activities"? Have you set a breakpoint at the point where you set the tint color to ensure it's being called?

Comment: Well, when you select mail, you get Apple's email app, and it shows the custom tint. So that is being called.
The "Activities" list is a system modal as near as I can tell. I have not found a way to set that from either inside the subclass of the UIActivityViewController or from the class calling same.
Am sure I must be missing something.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint or log a debug statement at `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor myDarkerColor]];` to verify that it's being called when you go to Activities?

Comment: It is called in the completionHandler when the UIActivityViewControlller is presented. It is not called when the system generated "Activities" view is called, nor is it called when Apple's email program is chosen, but Apple's email program's status bar is the correct color and it is not if I remove the appearance setting call.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help, Kyle. I still can't believe that this navigation bar cannot be colored.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113771/discussion-between-davidb-and-kyle-parent).

Answer (score 0):

Looking as to why I was seeing white text to begin with, a colleague pointed out that the app was likely setting the appdelegate.window to white.

So now right before I alloc the UIActivityViewController, I set the window to the tint I want:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window setTintColor:[UIColor myColor]];
```

Then in the UIActivityViewController completionWithItemsHandler I set it back to it's original color.

While this doesn't set the UINavigationBar to the theme color, it does set the "Done" button to that allowing the user to see it.